# In Sublime 2, is it possible to add text-column functionality to simple text files, for code-clarity?

Tags: sublime-text-2, text-formatting

This is hard to explain, but I'm not talking about re-indent; I'm asking if there's a simple way for simple text files to all match to the same formatting, using spaces, like a table with columns. [Example of similar idea.](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublimetableeditor/7077)

I use a lot of text files, and I comment on them heavily. I also look at the file once in a while to re-familiarize myself. Like this git bash profile (ignore the code, I want this two column setup!):

```
alias irb="ruby -S irb"                     # Instead of spamming space,
alias xp="explorer ."                       # everytime I add a new line,
alias reload="source ~/.bash_profile"       # I want these comments formatted here!
alias la="cat ~/.bash_profile"    # Argghhh..I'm unformatted :(
```

I'm open to other ideas instead of something like this! Thank you.

Comment: You could try [AlignTab](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AlignTab).There you can align with arbitrary regex and also set a keybinding with predefined user input.

Comment: @r-stein Thank you, that looks amazing.